# Hypergeometric calculation

Tags: probability

In a certain region, there are **25** animals, **5** of them are tagged. Suppose that **10** animals from that region are selected at random. Find the probability that none of them are tagged.

My work :

**X~H(N=25, K=5, n=10)**
I then inputted it into the hypergeometric formula: **P(X=0) = [binom(5,0) * binom(20,10)] / binom(25,10)** ... but I do not understand why I have to input into the calculator as: **[20!/(10!*10!)] / [25!/(10!*15!)]**, in order to get the correct answer of 0.0565. Any clarification is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Depends on your calculator. In general $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. Some calculators have a $\binom{n}{k}$ function. If yours does, maybe you were using the machine incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! I know what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\binom{5}{0} = \frac{5!}{0! (5-0)!} = \frac{5!}{5!} = 1.$$  $$\binom{20}{10} = \frac{20!}{10!(20-10)!} = \frac{20!}{10! 10!}.$$  $$\binom{25}{10} = \frac{25!}{10!(25-10)!} = \frac{25!}{10! 15!}.$$  So, what you wrote, $$\frac{\binom{5}{0} \binom{20}{10}}{\binom{25}{10}},$$ is equivalent to what you should type into the calculator.  If your calculator has a dedicated button for calculating binomial coefficients, you could use that too; it often looks like `nCr` or something of that sort.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now know where I've been going wrong.

Comment: @heropup great answer. I was wondering if you can assist my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283356/whats-the-probability-to-choose-the-3rd-person-moving-up-to-the-next-round